# Migrating a project from Final Cut Pro to Kdenlive

Tags: ubuntu, macos, kdenlive

I created video projects in Final Cut Pro when I had access to it through my university and now I want to migrate them to Kdenlive on Ubuntu. I installed Kdenlive 22 (version 23 would always crash), install OpenTimelineIO system-wide, exported a project in Final Cut Pro to XML, and changed the `src` on the source file from:

```
src="file:///Volumes/some_drive/Final%20Cut%20Pro/some_project/Original%20Media/some%20take.mp4"
```

to

```
src="/media/some_drive/Final Cut Pro/some_project/Original Media/some take.mp4"
```

I get a window with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/otioconvert", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio/console/otioconvert.py", line 243, in main
    result_tl = otio.adapters.read_from_file(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio/adapters/__init__.py", line 137, in read_from_file
    return adapter.read_from_file(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio/adapters/adapter.py", line 119, in read_from_file
    result = self._execute_function(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio/plugins/python_plugin.py", line 153, in _execute_function
    return (getattr(self.module(), func_name)(**kwargs))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 1147, in read_from_string
    return FcpxXml(input_str).to_otio()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 774, in to_otio
    return self._from_library()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 785, in _from_library
    return self._from_event(self.fcpx_xml.find("./library/event"))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 792, in _from_event
    container.append(self._from_project(project))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 797, in _from_project
    timeline.tracks = self._squence_to_stack(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 835, in _squence_to_stack
    offset, lane = self._offset_and_lane(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 951, in _offset_and_lane
    parent_format_id = self._format_id_for_clip(parent, default_format)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 1000, in _format_id_for_clip
    ).find("sequence")
      ^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

It seems that the OpenTimelineIO adapter cannot find the Final Cut Pro library event, so do I need to export something more from Final Cut Pro? How can I find which track or media item is throwing this problem? Or how can I tell Kdenlive to ignore the problematic files and do its best at importing the project?

## Update

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725224/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-find-when-converting-with for a workaround.